# Echoing several variable in random order

Tags: php, variables, random

I'm making simple test script with PHP+mysql.
The script gives the question and SELECT with 4 options (answers).
1 of them is correct, 3 others are incorrect, retrieved from mysql table.
I have 4 variables and all works fine, but I need to retrieve these variables in random order.

```
$variable1='1';
$variable2='2';
$variable3='3';
$variable4='4';
```

Just need some direction what to learn, what method to use.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: hard to guess without seeing what you've tried

Comment: if your getting the answers from mysql you could do `ORDER BY RAND()` then they will be returned in a random order

Comment: Put them in an array and shuffle it.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3 I use this to retrieve 3 incorrect answers. But I also have 1 correct, so I need to make random ordering of all 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SELECT data from MySQL
- Store in an associative array
- [shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle) the array

http://codepad.org/6R9LsGIy

```
<?php

$arrAnswers = array("a", "b", "c", "d");

shuffle($arrAnswers);

print_r($arrAnswers);

/* Example Ouput: 
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => d
    [2] => a
    [3] => c
) */
```

As you've said you have these variables;

> $variable1='1';
>   $variable2='2';
>   $variable3='3';
>   $variable4='4';

```
$arrAnswers = array($variable1,$variable2,$variable3,$variable4);
```

There are more elegant ways, but with the information given, this is the best I can do :)

Comment: I stuck on this.. I failed converting WHILE results into variables.. Can you tell me what is the better way to put WHILE results into ARRAY?

Comment: How are you fetching the results from the database? (It may be worth while opening another question?)

Comment: I got it! I just needed mysql_fetch_assoc